# Верстка: как разместить текст по центру относительно картинки?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Есть такой код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Работа</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/reset.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page">
            <div class="header">
                <img alt="Логотип" src="./img/logo.jpg"  class="logoimg" />123123
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

и css:

```
.page {
    width: 1024px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -512px;
}

.header {

}

.logoimg {
    float: left;
}
```

Нужно разместить текст по центру относительно картинки. `vertical-align: middle;` почему-то не помогло, даже если задать родительскому блоку фиксированную длину.

Comment: высота картинки постоянна и неизменна? надпись должна быть по центру снизу или по центру справа?

Comment: а если использовать картинку как бэкграунд?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.header {
    background-image: URL(//www.gravatar.com/avatar/?s=100);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    123123
</div>
```

- `line-height` = высоте изображения
- `font-size` = какой нужно размер шрифта
- `background-repeat: no-repeat;` - не повторять картинку, если она размером на весь хидер. Если она из повторяемого кусочка, то не пишем данное свойство.

А `vertical-align: middle;` с дивами работает, если задать диву табличный стиль отображения `display: table`. Но в ИЕ6, 7 не работает.